# accessing chrome dev tools from chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I want to be able to access the dev tools network tab and copy some urls from there. Is it possible? I want the extension itself to access the current page's dev tool network tab and do stuff. Searched in google but did not find anything specific about this.

Comment: Effort _not_ demonstrated here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me simply quote the description of [`chrome.devtools.network` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools_network):

> Use the `chrome.devtools.network` API to retrieve the information about network requests displayed by the Developer Tools in the Network panel.

*You need to work on your Google-Fu..*

---

That said, some comments.

This API is accessible when Dev Tools are open - since it's designed to be used for extensions *to* Dev Tools themselves. There's [an explanation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools) of what kind of extensions use this and how.

If you need to access this data when Dev Tools are closed, your next best bet is `chrome.debugger` API, that communicates with the page using the same protocol as Dev Tools themselves. Do note: it's a very heavy hammer, and it stops working when real Dev Tools are opened.